# kotlin, how to find a match of iframe tag with special src in html

Tags: html, regex, iframe, kotlin

Would like detect from a html content for an iframe tag with special src

```
<iframe width="100% !important" height="800px" src="//specical.com/external/widget/api.php?height=800px&amp;width=640px&amp; blablabal" ...... ></iframe>
```

the only part in concern is:

it is an iframe and has the src="//specical.com/external/widget/api.php?, and the src part could be placed in different place of the iframe string.
Dont care about what else is within the iframe.

how to use regex in kotlin to find a match?

I made one:

```
val patternString = "(?:<iframe\\s)(?:[^<]*)(?:src=\\s*)(?:\"//specical.com/external/widget/api.php\"\\s*)(?:[^>]*)>"
```

seems not working.

Thanks!

Comment: `document.querySelector("iframe[src*='specical.com']")` ...the attribute selector, read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Hmm, that one might not work in `kotlin` though...so you need to check it out, but leave the comment for other use cases

Comment: Use: '<iframe.*src=\"([^?\"]*)' then group1 will contain the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, this works

`<iframe(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\ssrc\s*=\s*(?:(['"])(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?(?:specical\.com/external/widget/api\.php?)(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>`

https://regex101.com/r/gUEfvy/1

```
 < iframe
 (?= \s )
 (?=                           # Asserttion for:  src  (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s src \s* = \s* 
      (?:
           ( ['"] )                      # (1)
           (?:
                (?! \1 )
                [\S\s] 
           )*?
           (?:                           # 
                specical\.com/external/widget/api\.php? 
           )
           (?:
                (?! \1 )
                [\S\s] 
           )*?
           \1 
      )
 )
                               # Have the src attribute, just match the rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+

 >                             # End  tag
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems working:

```
val patternString = "(?:<iframe\\s)(?:[^<]*)(?:src=\\s*)(?:\"\\/\\/specical\\.com/external\\/widget\\/api.php?\\s*?)(?:[^>]*)>"
val pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString)
val matcher = pattern.matcher(str)
```

i'm sure there is better one